# Do the feats Combat Casting, Warrior Priest, and Uncanny Concentration stack?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats

I'm looking to build a close ranged caster character and was wondering if these three feats stack. I know that Combat Casting and Uncanny Concentration stack with each other, but how does Warrior Priest fit in with them?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site! Nice first question; +1. If you haven't, I recommend the [Tour] for a nice introduction, and once you get 20 rep (should be soon!), feel free to join the [Chat]!

Answer (score 4):

**It Stacks**

*It is an unnamed bonus so it applies as is.*

---

**Warrior Priest**

*Your religion is both a shield and a weapon in battle.*

**Prerequisites**
    : Ability to cast divine spells, domain or mystery class feature.

**Benefit**
    : You gain a +1 bonus on initiative checks and a **+2 bonus** on concentration checks made to cast a spell or use a spell-like ability when casting defensively
    or while grappled.